# How to create a mobile blockchain application

Tags: react-native, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I’m currently trying to make a very simple dapp where users can mint their own nfts and sell it to other users. Im aware of how to do this on the web using react js However I’m lost on how to implement this in react native for mobile apps. My current understanding is to use truffle, web3.js and the MetaMask extension to build the app but how would this be changed/ modified for a mobile app(for example I’ve heard of doing something with infura ). What is a general outline/process for building an app that communicate with the eth blockchain.  Also if you could recommend some good resources on building mobile dapps that communicate with the etherium block chain that would be really helpful, I can't really find any for some reason.

Edit: I would like to create an ios app if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

On a mobile application you can use [WalletConnect mobile link](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking). It provides somewhat similar experience as signing transactions on MetaMask on desktop.